# How to separate personal Facebook from professional FB while getting full benefit of FB?

Tags: software-industry, socializing, social-media

I am a web based software engineer in Sri Lanka and I have own my web design business. It is really important to engage with Facebook groups to get local projects. That's how you build a network and get local projects.

But I don't like to use my personal Facebook profile to start group discussions and answer questions on the group. I don't like to post "I am doing web design business, etc" on my personal profile either. I want to use my personal profile to just connect with my friends and family.

Yes, I can create a FB fan page. I have one. But I can't join groups as a page. Facebook doesn't allow it.

So how can I engage with FB groups without mixing my personal life with professional life?

Comment: Have you tried to create your company Facebook page?

Comment: @A0o I have mentioned that I have created a company FB page in question. But Facebook don't allow to pages to join with FB groups... There are a few FB groups in my country which audience is very targeted audince for my business. So engage with them is really important....

Comment: Yes, some folks create a "company" profile that is separate from their actual profile. I think that is smart considering people been terminated for things they posted on their personal profiles.

Comment: stop using facebook?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems like more of a question about Facebook functionality than a workplace question.

Comment: why not just share all your details online about your self? that way you get the full benefit of fb without fb

Comment: Use LinkedIn. If you want to use Facebook for business purposes, you have to pay for it. That is why they are making it so difficult for you to use Facebook like you want to.

Comment: We are not Facebook customer support. If Facebook doesn't allow a "page" join a group, then it means you cannot do that unless they change their mind somehow. We cannot help you figure out how to circumvent it. What you can do is make use of what they do allow, which is to join the group as an individual profile. If you don't want to do that either, you are asking for the impossible.

Comment: Related question: [Should we maintain the difference between personal and professional contacts?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3867/should-we-maintain-the-difference-between-personal-and-professional-contacts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest answer to this (I've found), is one of two things;

## Create a second profile using your work e-mail (not advised)

While technically [against the terms of service](https://www.facebook.com/help/975828035803295) unless you are reported no-one will check in all likelihood **but be aware there is a risk Facebook will find out and take action.**

I wouldn't advise this due to the ToS.

However as a Facebook app developer, I've found this quite handy to have second accounts for different projects.

## Privacy settings & lists

Facebook has several features for [filtering posts and creating lists for people](https://en-gb.facebook.com/help/325807937506242/).

I'd look into making all of your posts viewable to 'friends only' (by default and retroactively), then creating a list specifically for those that add you for work reasons whilst removing them from friends (I split mine off into different categories and industries, such as web design or game development).

Relevant posts are then made with the audience set specifically to those lists and personal posts are set so that friends only can see them (you are also able to set defaults and retroactively change all posts in your privacy settings).

I'd then look at [creating a page](https://en-gb.facebook.com/pages/create) that can then be used as a workplace (I believe local business or company does this) and setting your workplace to this. That way you can make your posts on this page and then share posts from here that only go out to your work lists.

You should then tinker with your privacy settings to ensure everything you wouldn't want someone classed as a friend not to see be hidden.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Using same name in both account?

Comment: @iamthemoststupidperson up to you on that one, I personally went with the business or project name when I did that. for actual work-related groups option 2 works well for me

Comment: Encouraging someone to violate ToS of another site because "they are unlikely to catch you" is not cool. Don't do that.

Comment: @maskedman as said in the answer, there's a risk in doing so. The main meat of the answer is in the second part of tinkering with privacy settings, I'm not encouraging but just providing a few options and their upsides/downsides

Answer (score 2):

Facebook doesn't allow you to [create more than one personal account](https://www.facebook.com/help/975828035803295) for yourself - I expect you have explored this option and know this already.

What you can do is set the [audience](https://www.facebook.com/help/167941163265974) when you post so you can control who sees what you post, although this might not cover your needs.

I really suggest that you post this on the [Facebook community](https://www.facebook.com/help/community) to ask this question from the experts.  There's sure to be people there in your same position.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond creating two accounts (which isn't advisable as it's against the ToS and Facebook have a reputation of catching / blocking these reasonably easily) there's a few things you can do:

- Use your personal Facebook account for business only, and move all your social, personal content elsewhere. May not be an option if your friendship group is only on Facebook, but it's worth considering.
- While you can't *join* Facebook groups as a page / business, you should still be able to post comments / posts in a group as one (there's a drop-down arrow by the text box where you write your post that will let you select who you're posting as.) This should allow you to still post to these groups under a professional guise using your private account, and may be the best middle ground option to take.
- Use your personal account to post "public" content that's not an advert, so would also be interesting to friends / family. Set all personal content to "friends only", then start a blog where you're talking about interesting trends in the industry; post those as public posts to your Facebook profile. Not an all out solution to posting in groups of course, but friends / family may well still be interested in the sort of thing that you're writing, and then from a public perspective all your potential clients will see is "professional" type content.